# Table with full month view with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aggregate

wanted to create a table just like this 
[image]

(ignore the styling). i got confuse how to formate the data to make this table in html.

```
$scope.toddlers = [
{
  "name": "a",
  "day": 1,
  "total": 3
},
{
  "name": "b",
  "day": 2,
  "total": 4
},
{
  "name": "c",
  "day": 4,
  "total": 1
}
];
```

i think i need to change my data format or something i just can't make this table right. how should i format my data to give this result.

FYI: i am getting my data by using mongodb aggregate.

[plunker link](https://codepen.io/fatpandaaaa/pen/xgKOpL)

Comment: It is *impossible* to answer the question as it is currently presented.  You posted a screenshot of a possible layout, but no code at all showing any HTML, and a single code snippet of an array that makes no sense in relation to the screenshot provided.

Comment: added a plunker link please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet can produce the layout which you're desiring of:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th ng-repeat="day in days">{{day}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="toddler in toddlers">
    <td>{{toddler.name}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="day in days">
      <span ng-if="toddler.day === day">{{toddler.total}}</span>
      <span ng-if="toddler.day !== day">0</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It first repeats the days in `th`, with one extra `th` before all of days. Then if current toddler's day matches the current day, it shows `toddler.total`, otherwise `0` using `ng-if` directive.